# Integers as sums and differences of three dodecahedral numbers infinitely many different ways?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It was shown previously that the number 1 can be written as the sum and difference of at most three different tetrahedral numbers infinitely many different ways. But the dodecahedral numbers are a subset of the tetrahedral numbers. So is it possible that 1 can be written as the sum and difference of at most three dodecahedral numbers infinitely many different ways? Do all integers have this property?

Comment: Does "sum and difference" mean that any of the 4 possibilities (of how many are subtracted) is allowed, or do you insist on, say, ++- or some other sign pattern?

Comment: Reference for the result on tetrahedral numbers? Definition of dodecahedral numbers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson a) obvious, subtract $k-1$-th and $T_{k-1}$-th triangular numbers from $T_k$-th one b) using Google is still free

Comment: @Denis, I could do without the wiseassery. The definition of dodecahedral number should be given in the body of the question. It should not be necessary for everyone to go to Google just to understand the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, here's the link for the result on tetrahedral numbers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405631/prove-that-1-is-the-sum-of-three-tetrahedral-numbers-infinitely-many-different?rq=1

Comment: @GerryMyerson, here's the definition of dodecahedral numbers from Wikipedia: A dodecahedral number is a figurate number that represents a dodecahedron. The nth dodecahedral number is given by the formula $n(3n-1)(3n-2)/2$.

Comment: @Denis, judging from the mathoverflow link, there's nothing obvious about the tetrahedral result.

Comment: Have you done any computations with the dodecahedrals, Benjamin? Found lots of representations of $1$?